# on touchmove modify each element touched

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I've been searching around for this and can't seem to find anything.

Basically I've binded a "touchmove" event (via jQuery) to a set of divs.. what I was hoping would happen is, as you drag across each div (with out touchend) the div's attr "xyz" toggles from 0 to 1 aka meaning it's been touched.

```
$("#itBoardFront div").on('touchmove',function(e){
    $(this).attr('data-hit',1);
})
```

As you can assume, this is not working.  Only the element that's actually being hit on and moved on is getting the data-hit =1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by catching the coordinates of the touch end positions then comparing it with each potential div's x,y,w,h.

Comment: Can I maybe see an example of this solution? Having the exact same scenario in my code at the moment :)

Comment: Laust, basically just: if mouse over area run function that foreach's every div and compares x+y+w+h to the mouse position.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to 'touch and then move' per div. This is due to the way the events are fire on your elements. You can see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/MpJUR/6/
In each div (except the first one that took it by default) you need to click/touch first and then move in order to get the event trigger.
BTW, the event will be trigger on each 'move' to it's not efficient. You might want to catch 'touchstart' per div and/or just work with 'touchmove' on a parent elem that contain all the divs.

Comment: Some what close.  However, I need it so when you click over one and move to any div, so the "any" div should also get the data-hit.